# Angular 4 Component Rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

Simple question, no code involved. In what sequence or logic do Angular 4 components get loaded?

I ask because, I am having issues understanding placement of HTML, Script tags, CDN's in the Index, Root Component vs. Child components.

I am using HighCharts JS to render graphs on a nested "MarketComponent". I place all the code on Index.html and it works. But when I tried several combinations of imports using the market.component.html, it will not render on that Route.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Not a simple question. You do need to come up with an example that shows the problem. You are asking about a whole of different subjects and any answer will be all over the place.

Comment: do you use angular-cli or systemjs?

Answer (score -2):

hey bro I think this is what you are looking

https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks